# How to list processes belonging to a network namespace?

Tags: linux, process, network-namespaces

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, and the `ip` utility does not have `ip netns identify <pid>` option, I tried installing new `iproute`, but still, the option *identify* doesn't 
seem to be working!.

If I were to write a script (or code) to list all processes in a network-namespace, or given a PID, show which network-namespace it belongs to, how should I proceed ?
(I need info on a handful of processes, to check if they are in the right `netns`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
netns=myns
find -L /proc/[1-9]*/task/*/ns/net -samefile /run/netns/"$netns" | cut -d/ -f5
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
print -l /proc/[1-9]*/task/*/ns/net(e:'[ $REPLY -ef /run/netns/$netns ]'::h:h:t)
```

It checks the inode of the file which the `/proc/*/task/*/ns/net` symlink points to agains those of the files bind-mounted by `ip netns add` in `/run/netns`. That's basically what `ip netns identify` or [`ip netns pid`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213054/list-processes-belonging-to-a-network-namespace/213066?noredirect=1#comment361509_213066) in newer versions of `iproute2` do.

That works with the 3.13 kernel as from the `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` package on Ubuntu 12.04, but not with the 3.2 kernel from the first release of 12.04 where `/proc/*/ns/*` are not symlinks and each `net` file there from every process and task gets a different inode which can't help determine namespace membership.

Support for that was added by [that commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=98f842e675f96ffac96e6c50315790912b2812be) in 2011, which means you need kernel 3.8 or newer.

With older kernels, you could try and run a program listening on an ABSTRACT socket in the namespace, and then try to enter the namespace of every process to see if you can connect to that socket there like:

```
sudo ip netns exec "$netns" socat abstract-listen:test-ns,fork /dev/null &
ps -eopid= |
  while read p; do
    nsenter -n"/proc/$p/ns/net" socat -u abstract:test-ns - 2> /dev/null &&
      echo "$p"
  done
```

Comment: I used the first form (I use `bash`), but I get an error when I run  `find -L /proc/*/task/*/ns/net -samefile /run/netns/"$netns"
find: '/proc/self/task/8964/ns/net': No such file or directory`  (where `8964` is current pid [`$$`] ) - should I be running this in the `default` namespace ?

Comment: @vyom, yes from the top level pid and mount namespace (though I suppose you could create netns'es in other mount namespaces which would void that command).

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me :(. I tried from `/`, and I have created the `netns`, in the usual way - `ip netns add`, and I can see it in `/var/run/netns/`. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: @vyom, does `grep /run/netns /proc/self/mountinfo` report anything? What kernel version are you using (`uname -rs`)?

Comment: The error about `/proc/self` is to be expected when using sudo or a shell that doesn't expand globs in the process they're executing the command in. I've edited the answer to avoid it (but that wouldn't prevent listing the pids)

Comment: @vyom, you must have a 3.2 kernel. I confirm it doesn't work there.

Comment: `ip netns help` lists the command `netns pids NAME` which, as I think, is supposed to list all of the pids in a name netns.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I have `Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS`, where `uname -a` shows `3.5.0-23-generic`, so maybe I am out of luck! :(

Comment: @vyom, yes. See the alternative I gave for older kernels. That would probably mean you'd need to compile a newer version of util-linux as I don't think 12.04's ones will include nsenter. Namespaces were still quite experimental when 12.04 came out.

Comment: @vyom. Note that [that 3.5 kernel has been out of support since April 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support). You'd probably want to upgrade to the 3.13 (linux-image-generic-lts-trusty) or downgrade to 3.2.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Thanks.  Yes, `nsenter` is not present, there is a plan to move to `Ubuntu 14.04`, if that doesn't happen soon enough, I will  get a new version of `util-linux`.

Comment: @mikeserv, I dont have the `pids` option.

Comment: @vyom, note that  I was note suggesting to upgrade to 14.04, just to install the `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` 12.04 package to get a supported kernel in your 12.04. You'd get that kernel automatically if you installed 12.04.5 now.

Answer (score 6):

`ps $(ip netns pids myns)`
where `myns` is your namespace

Comment: Pretty similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354038/117549

Comment: some  namespace don't have a file in /var/run/netns/, so the namespace is no NAME,  (such as  process 1 , the init process).  ip command can not work in this situation

Answer (score 4):

The question specifically mentions Ubuntu 12.04, but I note that on newer distros like 16.04 there is a command that does exactly this: `ip netns pids <nsname>`

Comment: Unfortunately, `ip netns` only works on network namespaces bind-mounted on `/run/netns` (also `/var/run/netns`). It is completely ignorant to any other network namespaces, either bind-mounted in other places, such as `/run/docker`, and it especially is totally ignorant of `/proc`.

Answer (score 1):

**[Namespace-Lister:](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Namespace-Lister)**

You can use **[listns.py](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Namespace-Lister)** with: `./listns.py` or `python2 listns.py` 
 (*source: [github-mirror](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Namespace-Lister) and [article](https://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=251)*; *all credit to [Ralf Trezeciak](https://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=251)*)

**[IP-Netns](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html):**

Can be done with the following (replace $namespace-name):

```
ip netns pids $namespace-name | xargs ps -o pid,command -p
```

**[Nsutils](https://github.com/rd235/nsutils)**

Provide `netnslist` that list all the net namespaces and all the processes running in each namespace:

Answer (score 0):

When running inside the container as opposed to outside, I found the -samefile trick sadly didn't work. Not sure why as it was the same inode. Anyway, this however did work, just in case it is of use to anyone:

```
netns=mynamespace
inode=$(ls -i /var/run/netns/$netns | cut -f1 -d" ")
pids=$(find -L /proc/[1-9]*/task/*/ns/net -inum $inode | cut -f3 -d"/" | uniq)
ps -p $pids
```